# Unable to fetch URL with Cordova inappbrowser plugin

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am using IONIC 1 to make an app in which we need to fetch URL of the loading page in the webview.
I am using [Cordova Inappbrowser plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) and it works fine except few websites like FLIPKART.com etc.

Can someone please suggest what could be the issue? I am unable to fetch URL of the inside pages of flipkart.com mobile site.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error message, I am just getting home page url and not inside pages.

Comment: for example I am not getting this page url (https://www.flipkart.com/puma-step-stripe-flip-flops/p/itmegntzcgrfgvsz?pid=SFFEGNTZEXK4UBH7&srno=b_1_2&otracker=hp_omu_Deals%20of%20the%20day%20_1_Under%20%E2%82%B9699_TTRA9HKT6G_0&lid=LSTSFFEGNTZEXK4UBH7P9WX7N) but I am getting home page url (flipkart.com)

Comment: @georgeawg Did you get a chance to check my last comments? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Try encoding the `"₹"` character as `"%E2%82%B9"`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: Try omitting the tracking information `https://www.flipkart.com/puma-step-stripe-flip-flops/p/itmegntzcgrfgvsz?pid=SFFEGNTZEXK4UBH7`

Comment: But how can I omit the tracking information, I am unable to fetch URL at all in flipkart case, I am just getting "https://flipkart.com " when I am fetching URL from product pages/inside pages